# Hidden right sidebar using position only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi  I have build 2 sidebars. One left sidebar which is hidden by offsetting the element off the screen and giving him negative values for left attribute.
The right side menu in the other hand, doesn't disappear correctly and I can still scroll over horizontally and see this menu.
How can I hide the right sidebar without using display:none or visibility:hidden.
I am adding the code.

```js
   $(function () {
        $("#arrow_btn").click(function () {
            $("#navbar, .upper_menu").toggleClass('active');
            $("#upper_left_menu").toggleClass('open_left_menu');
            console.log("look for arrow btn element");
            console.log("upper_left_menu", $("#upper_left_menu"));
            console.log('$("#navbar")', $("#navbar"));
        });

        $(".project_item").click(function (event) {
            var list = $(this).siblings();
            var i = $(this).find('i');
            $(list).toggleClass('closed_nested_list');
            if ($(i).hasClass('fa-plus')) {
                $(i).removeClass('fa-plus');
                $(i).addClass('fa-minus');
            } else {
                $(i).addClass('fa-plus');
                $(i).removeClass('fa-minus');
            }
            console.log('traverse over all project items');
            console.log('i', i);
            console.log('list', list);
        });
     
        $("#email").click(function(){
          console.log("you clicked email ya ya ");
          $("#right-navbar").css("display",'inline-block');
          $("#right-navbar, .upper_menu").toggleClass('active');
            $("#upper_right_menu").toggleClass('open_right_menu');
        });
     
     $(".list_item").click(function(){
       console.log('you clicked list item');
       $("#chatWrapper").toggleClass('active');
$("#right-navbar").toggleClass('aside');
       $("#upper_right_menu").toggleClass('aside_right_menu');
     });
        
    });
```

```css
#arrow_btn{
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight:normal;
    }

    #arrow_btn:hover{
        color: #3983C4;
    }

    .upper_menu {     
        display: block;
        background-color: #F2F6F7;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    #upper_left_menu {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        z-index: 1;
        -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -moz-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -ms-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -o-transition: all 600ms ease;
        transition: all 600ms ease;
    }

#upper_right_menu{
        z-index: 1;
        -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -moz-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -ms-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -o-transition: all 600ms ease;
        transition: all 600ms ease;
}

    .open_left_menu {
        margin-left: 223px;
      
    }

 .open_right_menu {
        margin-right: 223px;
   -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -moz-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -ms-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -o-transition: all 600ms ease;
        transition: all 600ms ease;
    }
.aside_right_menu{
  margin-right: 43.5%;
}
    #upper_right_menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        right: 0px;
    }

    #exclamation-triangle,
    #envelope {
        font-size: 24px;
    }

    .warning,
    .email {
        margin: 10px;
    }
    
 #navbar {
        position: absolute;
        left: -16em;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow: 4px 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        z-index: 1;
        cursor: pointer;
        animation: 10s;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    #navbar ul {
        width: 224px;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 1em;
    }

#right-navbar{
  
  position: absolute;
        right: -16em;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        z-index: 1;
        cursor: pointer;
        animation: 10s;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
}

#chatWrapper{
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
        right: -32em;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width:338.667px;
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        z-index: 1;
        cursor: pointer;
        animation: 10s;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
}

#right-navbar ul {
        width: 224px;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 1em;
    }
/* hovering */
    #chatWrapper,
    #chatWrapper *
    #right-navbar,
    #right-navbar *,
    #navbar,
    #navbar * {
        -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -moz-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -ms-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -o-transition: all 600ms ease;
        transition: all 600ms ease;
    }

    #navbar.active {
        left: 0px;
    }

  #right-navbar.active{
      right: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -moz-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -ms-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -o-transition: all 600ms ease;
        transition: all 600ms ease;
  }
 #right-navbar.aside{
      right: 26.5%;
  }
#chatWrapper.active{
  right:0%;
}

    .nested_list {
        display: inline-block;
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .closed_nested_list {
        display: none;
    }

    .project_item {
        font-family: 'Segue UI', Calibri, arial, verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="upper_menu">
    <div id="upper_left_menu">
        <span id="arrow_btn"  class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="upper_right_menu">
        <a href="#" class="warning"><i id="exclamation-triangle" class=" fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i><span id="exclamation_notifications_count">2</span></a>
        <a href="#" id="email" class="email"><i id="envelope" class=" fa fa-envelope-o"></i><span id="email_notifications_count">5</span></a>
    </div>
</nav>
<nav id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li class="project_container">
            <span class="project_item" >
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>  
                FDR Project
            </span>
            <ul id="listOne" class="nested_list closed_nested_list">
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit01</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit02</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit03</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="project_container">
            <span class="project_item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>  Niagara Project</span>
            <ul id="listTwo" class="nested_list closed_nested_list">
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit01</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit02</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit03</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="project_container">
            <span class="project_item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>  Jarvis Plant</span>
            <ul id="listThree" class="nested_list closed_nested_list">
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit01</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit02</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit03</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="project_container">
            <span class="project_item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>  Jarvis Plant</span>
            <ul id="listFour" class="nested_list closed_nested_list">
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit01</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit02</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit03</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<nav id="right-navbar">
    <ul>
        <li class="project_container">
            <span class="project_item" >
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>  
                FDR Project
            </span>
            <ul id="listOne" class="nested_list closed_nested_list">
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit01</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit02</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit03</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="project_container">
            <span class="project_item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>  Niagara Project</span>
            <ul id="listTwo" class="nested_list closed_nested_list">
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit01</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit02</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit03</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="project_container">
            <span class="project_item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>  Jarvis Plant</span>
            <ul id="listThree" class="nested_list closed_nested_list">
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit01</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit02</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit03</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="project_container">
            <span class="project_item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>  Jarvis Plant</span>
            <ul id="listFour" class="nested_list closed_nested_list">
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit01</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit02</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit03</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<nav id="chatWrapper">
  Hello Chat Warpper
</nav>
```

A small piece of the original code without the left menu and only the right menu

```js
   $(function () {
     
        $("#email").click(function(){
          console.log("you clicked email ya ya ");
          $("#right-navbar").css("display",'inline-block');
          $("#right-navbar, .upper_menu").toggleClass('active');
            $("#upper_right_menu").toggleClass('open_right_menu');
        });
     
     $(".list_item").click(function(){
       console.log('you clicked list item');
       $("#chatWrapper").toggleClass('active');
$("#right-navbar").toggleClass('aside');
       $("#upper_right_menu").toggleClass('aside_right_menu');
     });
        
    });
```

```css
#arrow_btn{
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight:normal;
    }

    #arrow_btn:hover{
        color: #3983C4;
    }

    .upper_menu {     
        display: block;
        background-color: #F2F6F7;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

#upper_right_menu{
        z-index: 1;
        -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -moz-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -ms-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -o-transition: all 600ms ease;
        transition: all 600ms ease;
}

    .open_left_menu {
        margin-left: 223px;
      
    }

 .open_right_menu {
        margin-right: 223px;
   -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -moz-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -ms-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -o-transition: all 600ms ease;
        transition: all 600ms ease;
    }
.aside_right_menu{
  margin-right: 43.5%;
}
    #upper_right_menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        right: 0px;
    }

    #exclamation-triangle,
    #envelope {
        font-size: 24px;
    }

    .warning,
    .email {
        margin: 10px;
    }
    
#right-navbar{
  
  position: absolute;
        right: -16em;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        z-index: 1;
        cursor: pointer;
        animation: 10s;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
}

#chatWrapper{
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
        right: -32em;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width:338.667px;
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        z-index: 1;
        cursor: pointer;
        animation: 10s;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
}

#right-navbar ul {
        width: 224px;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 1em;
    }
/* hovering */
    #chatWrapper,
    #chatWrapper *
    #right-navbar,
    #right-navbar * {
        -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -moz-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -ms-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -o-transition: all 600ms ease;
        transition: all 600ms ease;
    }

    #navbar.active {
        left: 0px;
    }

  #right-navbar.active{
      right: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -moz-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -ms-transition: all 600ms ease;
        -o-transition: all 600ms ease;
        transition: all 600ms ease;
  }
 #right-navbar.aside{
      right: 26.5%;
  }
#chatWrapper.active{
  right:0%;
}

    .nested_list {
        display: inline-block;
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .closed_nested_list {
        display: none;
    }

    .project_item {
        font-family: 'Segue UI', Calibri, arial, verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="upper_menu">
    <div id="upper_left_menu">
        <span id="arrow_btn"  class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="upper_right_menu">
        <a href="#" class="warning"><i id="exclamation-triangle" class=" fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i><span id="exclamation_notifications_count">2</span></a>
        <a href="#" id="email" class="email"><i id="envelope" class=" fa fa-envelope-o"></i><span id="email_notifications_count">5</span></a>
    </div>
</nav>
<nav id="right-navbar">
    <ul>
        <li class="project_container">
            <span class="project_item" >
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>  
                FDR Project
            </span>
            <ul id="listOne" class="nested_list closed_nested_list">
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit01</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit02</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit03</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="project_container">
            <span class="project_item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>  Niagara Project</span>
            <ul id="listTwo" class="nested_list closed_nested_list">
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit01</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit02</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit03</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="project_container">
            <span class="project_item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>  Jarvis Plant</span>
            <ul id="listThree" class="nested_list closed_nested_list">
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit01</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit02</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit03</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="project_container">
            <span class="project_item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>  Jarvis Plant</span>
            <ul id="listFour" class="nested_list closed_nested_list">
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit01</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit02</li>
                <li class="list_item"><img height="24" width="24" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2ev4vmw.png" />     Unit03</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<nav id="chatWrapper">
  Hello Chat Warpper
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you post only the relevant code (or preferably a small, separate example) without all the extra content?

Comment: this is the smallest code, I can publish. I want to demonstrate how the left sidebar menu works perfectly while the right sidebar menu doesn't work correctly.

Comment: but I will try to pass it to a small example

Comment: What if you add `overflow-x: hidden;` on the element containing your navbar?

Comment: I did it, look at the code, no effect.

Comment: I have add a shorter version of the code, it will be lovely if you could solve me this mysterious case.

Comment: I see it on the bar itself, but not on the parent (overflow keeps the child elements from escaping (or scrolling) the parent).  Based on the example, try adding it to the `body` element.

Comment: right-navbar doesn't have any parent, right-navbar has overflow-x: hidden;

Comment: Right.. the implied parent is `body` since there's no parent element.  Try adding `body { overflow-x: hidden; }` and see.  Here's a fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/xcesu4dq/

Comment: solve the problem. The question is, is this the right solution :/

Comment: Unless you want your page to scroll horizontally (for other reasons), I think it is... I'll add it as an answer for now... maybe someone else will have a better idea later.  :)

Comment: thx anyway for quick respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving answer from comments...

Add `overflow-x: hidden;` to the nav bar's parent element (in this example, the parent would be `body`).

This will keep the horizontal scroll bar from coming up when the nav bar moves off the right side of the screen.